# Cant Mount NTFS hdd on ubuntu server

Tags: mount, ntfs, ubuntu-12.04

i am trying to mount my NTFS 1.5TB hdd to my ubuntu server running version 12

I use this command

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /dummy
```

The error i get is this:

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

fdisk -l brings me this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
16 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2907021 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xfd17b6bb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  2930274303  1465136128    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00004c1b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          501758   976771071   488134657    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          501760   976771071   488134656   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/linxuServer-root: 495.6 GB, 495624126464 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60256 cylinders, total 968015872 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/linxuServer-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/linxuServer-swap_1: 4173 MB, 4173332480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 507 cylinders, total 8151040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/linxuServer-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 4173 MB, 4173332480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 507 cylinders, total 8151040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb7763384

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I have tried fuser -vm /dev/sdaand get this error:

```
                     USER PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/sda:            root     kernel swap  /dev/dm-2
                     root     kernel mount /dev
                     root          1 F.... init
                     root        330 F.... mountall
                     root        399 F.... upstart-udev-br
                     root        402 F.... udevd
                     root        533 F.... udevd
                     root        535 F.... udevd
                     root        818 F.... upstart-socket-
                     root        932 F.... smbd
                     messagebus    939 F.... dbus-daemon
                     root        941 F.... smbd
                     avahi       955 F.... avahi-daemon
                     avahi       956 F.... avahi-daemon
                     root       1070 F.... dhclient3
                     root       1113 F.... sshd
                     root       1151 F.... nmbd
                     root       1233 F.... getty
                     root       1238 F.... getty
                     root       1251 F.... getty
                     root       1254 F.... getty
                     root       1258 F.... winbindd
                     root       1262 F.... getty
                     root       1267 F.... winbindd
                     whoopsie   1286 F.... whoopsie
                     root       1288 F.... acpid
                     root       1291 F.... irqbalance
                     root       1329 F.... apache2
                     www-data   1332 F.... apache2
                     www-data   1334 F.... apache2
                     www-data   1335 F.... apache2
                     root       1403 F.... cron
                     daemon     1404 F.... atd
                     tomcat6    1450 f.... java
                     root       1624 f.... sabnzbdplus
                     root       1665 F.... getty
                     root       1677 F.... sshd
                     root       1679 F.... winbindd
```

i tried this:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /dummy
```

Got the error below:

```
    NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: It appears that the filesystem is already mounted. Does `/dev/sdb1` appear in the output of `mount` or for short does `mount | grep /dev/sdb1` have any output?

Comment: you made a typo in your mount command....see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm....your fdisk indicates that /dev/sda1 contains the NTFS volume.  Yet the mount command you submitted in your question:

```
  mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /dummy
```

indicates you are attempting to mount /dev/sdb1.  Which is indeed in use by Linux.

Thus the answer seems to be to use:

```
 mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /dummy
```

Comment: The last command is incorrect it should be `mount -f -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /dummy` but I don't recommend forcing a mount when the device is or might be already mounted.

Comment: Cheers. i tried that link and got another error. updating question

Comment: Hi. any suggestions? it now says my ntfs signature is missing?